# How to access shapefiles stored in Dropbox for Mac new version (/Library/CloudStorage)

Tags: dropbox, qgis

I usually store my shapefiles in a Dropbox folder (available offline). In the new version of Dropbox for Mac files are necessarily stored in `~/Library/CloudStorage`, which seems to prevent me from opening my shapefiles in QGis.
QGis's Data Source Manager in Browser mode can show some contents of the `Library` folder but it fails to show `/CloudStorage` folder. Drag and drop of the shapefile from Finder also fails and throws an `Invalid data source` error.

I can copy my shapefiles to a local folder, but I would like to keep them in dropbox to have them backed up. Is there a way to do so?

I am working in mac os Ventura, Dropbox v175.4.5569, QGis 3.28.7-Firenze